# petsc converting sequential matrix to parallel matrix

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Is it possible to convert a petsc sequential matrix to a petsc mpi matrix? I have a problem that needs parallel solution, but do not have access to parallel meshes. Using matsetvalues before solution is very very slow.. anyway to speed up the whole process?

Comment: Yes you have to change your code, change all the sequential parts to mpi